# bower svn is not installed or not in the PATH

Tags: svn, bower, bower-install

I executed command "bower install" and console say me
svn is not installed or not in the PATH
although in my environment variable "path" have C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin
Who faced with similar?
Google did not answer

Comment: need install slinkSVN,client tortoiseSvn not suitable

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the bower ENOSVN error with TortoiseSVN, even with it in my PATH variables.  The basic TortoiseSVN install doesn't support the "svn" command from the Windows command line, you may need to install that tool via the Tortoise installer (or install a different svn program).

Answer (score 0):

Select  and Install "Command Line Client tools" option of TortoiseSVN during the installation step for Tortoise SVN. If TortoiseSVN is already installed, you should be able to "Modify" the setup and add the "Command line client tools" install and complete the installation. Once this is done, the "svn" command line option should work under the windows command prompt. The above steps should fix the ENOSVN error.

Answer (score 0):

Try Subversion for Windows. It has a svn command and that is what you need.
https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/